# Why do I get an `npm ERR!` when running the Python quick start tutorial in Cloud Run?

Tags: python, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am building my first job in Cloud Run.  I am using Python.  I am following the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-python).

I am able to successfully deploy and run the job from source, but the logs show me `npm ERR!`s that make no sense to me.  I tried deploying a simpler HelloWorld as well, but get the same errors.

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR! npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR! npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR! npm run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/cnb/.npm/_logs/2023-09-28T07_27_51_794Z-debug-0.log
Container called exit(1).
```

I have no idea where it wants me to run `npm run`.  The deployment and running of the job appear to work just fine.  Although I don't see any of my code actually run.  I see nothing about npm in the Quickstart guide.

```
Job [job-quickstart] has successfully been deployed.
Execution [job-quickstart-6n4mj] has successfully started running.
```

I installed the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) like they said, and put it in the home directory like they preferred.  My jobs code is in another directory, and I am deploying from that other directory.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My billing account wasn't verified.  Once I verified it, I started over from step 1, and everything worked just fine.  Maybe I did something else different, but verifying my payment was the only change I noticed.  I tried to break it again, but it just worked now.  So strangely enough, I am going to say the solution is:

Make sure your billing account is verified in the payment overview page:
[image]